# Setting a global font-weight bold screwes up the bootstrap wysiwyg plugin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I've set [bootstrap wysiwyg](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) inside a popover. Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sgUhS/3/). Now if I add this:

```
* { font-weight: bold; }
#editor { font-weight: normal; }
```

It screwes up the bold directive entirely. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/sgUhS/5/). I tried `#editor *`, `.popover *` and other variations but nothing helps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution for this is instead of this:

```
* { font-weight: bold; }
```

to do this:

```
html { font-weight: bold; }
```

It might require me some extra work down the road, but it solves my problem.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/sgUhS/6/)